# OSError: ./peft-dialogue-summary-checkpoint-local does not appear to have a file named config.json

Tags: python, nlp, peft, config.json

I have trained an LLM model using LoRa. Now I am trying to have access to the trained model for evaluation using the following code:

```
peft_trainer.train()

peft_model_path="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\AI"

peft_trainer.model.save_pretrained(peft_model_path)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(peft_model_path)

instruct_model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\AI", torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16)
```

It's giving me error:

```
OSError: ./peft-dialogue-summary-checkpoint-local does not appear to have a file named config.json
```

my folder in directory:

`"C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\AI" has only managed to save files; adapter_config.json, adapter_model.bin,special_tokens_map.json,tokenizer.json,tokenizer_config.json`.

How do I get the `config.json` file saved in the folder?

I tried to access my trained model. I was expecting the

```
instruct_model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\AI", torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16)
```

to run without an error so that I should evaluate the model.